# How can I easily create a python argparse argument with an inverse?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

Using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) with Python 3, I'd like to create a complementary pair of arguments:

```
--log-file=~/some-default-log-filename.txt
--no-log-file
```

As the example implies, by default the log file arguments would have a default value (a filename). You could change that by specifying a different string value to `--log-file`, or remove the log file completely by specifying `--no-log-file`.

What's an elegant way to do this in argparse? I can't find any way to do inverse/complementary arguments at all, no mind about where one has a string argument.

The best would be if when I executed `args = parser.parse_args()`, `args.log_file` contained either the log file name (including a default one) or `None` if the `no-log-file` option had been specified.

Comment: have you looked at ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

Comment: Rob, I have (in fact I use it elsewhere), but that involves creating two options. The `--no` prefix is such a common concept I was hoping/assuming there was an argparse mechanism for supporting it directly.

Comment: Why not make it so if there is no log file, the user just *doesn't supply `--log-file`?*

Comment: jonrsharpe, unfortunately that fails the requirement of having a log file by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the end of this for a `store_const` based solution.

I recall seeing an old python bug issue that suggested extending `argparse` with some code that could automatically handle `--foo` and `--no-foo` and maybe some other variants.  Maybe I'll find that later.

But currently `argparse` does not have a mechanism that matches your specs.

The `nargs='?'` with `const` and `default` is intended to handle a 3 fold case like yours.

```
# no --foo, assign the 'default'
--foo # without arg, assign the 'const'
--foo arg  # assign the supplied string
```

While the syntax isn't exactly what you want, I think it gives your users the same control.

To get closer to your desired syntax you will have to create both the `logfile` argument, and the `no-log` argument, and then use a simple pos-parsing test to 'merge' the two.

```
parser.add_argument('--log-file', ....)
parser.add_argument('--no-log', action='store_true')
```

and later:

```
if args.no_log:
    args.log_file = None
```

If you had to create many argument pairs like this you could define a helper function:

```
def make_inverse_arg(parser, *args, **kwargs):
    parser.add_argument(*args, **kwargs)
    # define inverse
    arg1 = '--no-'+args[1][2:]
    parser.add_argument(arg1, action='store_true')
    # could be more robust, but you get the idea
    def post_test():
         ...
    return post_test
```

---

If `--no-foo` is defined as 'store_const' argument, `const=None` and same dest as `--foo`, then it will only put the `None` in the namespace when it is present.  `default=SUPPRESS` ensures that it does not put its own default into the namespace.

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--no-foo', dest='foo', action='store_const', const=None,
     default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('--foo',default='test')

In [329]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[329]: Namespace(foo='test')

In [330]: parser.parse_args('--foo xxx'.split())
Out[330]: Namespace(foo='xxx')

In [331]: parser.parse_args('--foo xxx --no-foo'.split())
Out[331]: Namespace(foo=None)

In [332]: parser.parse_args('--no-foo --foo xxx'.split())
Out[332]: Namespace(foo='xxx')

In [333]: parser.parse_args('--no-foo'.split())
Out[333]: Namespace(foo=None)
```

If there is a conflict the last of `--foo` and `--no-foo` determines what's in the namespace.

Comment: This seems to work best, and directly addresses my scenario. I like your generalised `make_inverse_arg` function.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *quite* what you're looking for, but I would do that as follows:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--log-file", 
    const="~/some-default-log-filename.txt", 
    default=None,
    dest="log_file",
    nargs="?"
)
```

This handles three cases:

- `... --log-file mylog.txt ...` - log to the user-specified file;
- `... --log-file ...` - log to the `const` default file; and
- `...` - use the `default` value `None`.

See [the docs on `nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) for more information.

Comment: Yep, that's a good start, thanks. But no, unfortunately it isn't what I'm looking for. The most important point is that the default *is* to log to somewhere. The user also needs to be able to switch the target of that log file, and to turn it off completely.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier I see. I think the direct answer to your question is *"no"*, then. You could e.g. define `type` as a custom function and allow the user to enter `--log-file=off` to deactivate the logging.